# Adding to group layers in loop is slow in ArcGIS Engine?

Tags: arcobjects, c#, arcgis-engine, arcgis-10.5, group-layer

I am using ArcGIS Engine 10.5.1.

I wanted to ask and see if anyone else has encountered this and or found a work around.  I have a loop in c# where I am taking a large set of layer files and adding them to the map.  I have tried this two ways but both ways seem to be equally slow (~10 minutes for ~180 layers).  The contents of the layers files are just shape objects.  Not a lot of data.  The first way I tried to achieve this is

```
IGroupLayer groupLayer = new GroupLayer();
foreach(SortedListLayers layer in MySortedListLayers)
{
    ILayerFile layerfile = new LayerFile();
    layerfile.Open(layer.location);
    groupLayer.Add(layerfile.Layer);
    layerfile.Close();
}
```

On the `groupLayer.Add` line there is more and more overhead  each time the call is made to complete adding the `layerfile.Layer` to the group even though the group is not yet on the map.  My alternative was to use `IMapLayers` and implement `IEnumLayers` on my `SortedListLayers` object (which only contains a sorted list of 'layers' and the location that it belongs to) and use the `maplayers.InsertLayersInGroup` call to try to diminish looping but that turned out even slower.

Comment: Does it take as long just to loop through the file list and add the layers to a `List<ILayer>` with no GroupLayer involved?

Comment: Did you try calling `ReleaseComObject` on layerfile at the bottom of the loop?

Comment: I did try both.  It takes a good amount of time without the group layer but eventually it needs to go in one, which also takes a fair amount of time. And I did try releasing the object each iteration but it did not seem to have an impact.  I even tried to create a single instance of the layer file and just re-use it but that actually ended up bieng slower

Comment: By "shape objects" do you mean shapefiles?  If so, are the shapefiles on a network share folder?  If you save the resulting grouplayer to a layerfile, does it take long to load into the map manually?

Comment: Yes shapefiles with metadata.  I hear shapefiles in general are pretty slow working with layerfiles but I couldn't have imagined this.  This is all local machine work.  I haven't tried that option before though

Comment: I would guess a network share folder would make things even slower.  I see no rule against moving `ILayerFile layerfile = new LayerFile()` outside the loop, before the `foreach`. Did you try that?

Comment: Also, performance with file geodatabases is usually much better than with shape files.

Comment: Yes that's what I meant when I said I tried to create a single instance and re-use it. It ended up feeling slower overall